# Optimize MySQL query order in the results using GROUP BY and count

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT vBrowser,iconBrowser, count(iconBrowser) as 'N'
FROM user_ip_tmp  WHERE code='9m9g9tsv2y'
GROUP BY iconBrowser
ORDER BY N DESC
LIMIT 40
```

And this works properly. But the delirious cause query took a long time.

```
Showing rows 0 - 17 ( 18 total, Query took 4.4189 sec)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please accept some answers (the big checkmark, not just the up arrow) in order to get better answers. You have 8 questions and zero accepts.

Comment: I apologized and I'm new in programming For this I do not have sufficient experience I hope help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Things that are in `WHERE` statement, should be indexed.

Try to use `EXPLAIN` statement before your `SELECT` to see what and how is used to retrief your requested results.

And if the column `code` is not an unique value, i would recommend to put it in some other table, where it is unique. Then build the query using `JOIN` though the `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: `code`
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  user_ip_tmp  ref  too  too  767  const  52899  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesor
`code`

Comment: @10neencom This means , that your query is not using an index

Comment: How do I solve this now do ALTER TABLE `user_ip_tmp` ADD INDEX(`code`)
And I take a lot of time and causes the stop mysql

Comment: Noone said that indexing a filled tableis fast , especially since you seem to index a varchar column. First time DBMS has to go through each row and add it to the index. I guess you did not reed the 3rd paragraph in my answer.